# Forwarding to the item page after the creation of the item via front end editing

Tags: custom-component, joomla-4.x, redirect, front-end

I wrote a small joomla 4 component and made it possible to create a new item in the frontend.

After creating a new item, Joomla core components usually redirects to a list view. But I want to redirect to the detail view of the item.

For example `/view=myitem&id=11:test&catid=3`

Unfortunately I do not know the `id` of the new item at the time of creation. Therefore I can not create the URL while creating the item.

Is there a way to do this that I do not see?

Comment: Could you post the save method of your Model that saves the item?

Answer (score 1):

If you're extending core form controller/model, you can access the ID through the model in controller's `postSaveHook()` method:

```
protected function postSaveHook(\Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\BaseDatabaseModel $model, $validData = [])
{
    $id = $model->getState($model->getName() . '.id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Joomla 3**'s documentation for inserting data into a database https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase#Inserting_a_Record mentiones:

```
$new_row_id = $db->insertid();
```

The **Joomla 4** code base still uses `$db->insertid();` at some places, so I suppose that it will work for your code as well.